# Designing numbering system with unsigned and signed ints

Tags: scala

I'm trying to design a numbering system around both unsigned integers and signed integers. Both of these types have an `underlying` value that represents the number in Scala's number system. Here is the type hierarchy I have so far.

```
sealed trait Number {
  def + (num : Number) : Number = ???
  def - (num : Number) : Number = ???
  def * (num : Number) : Number = ???
}

sealed trait SignedNumber extends Number

sealed trait UnsignedNumber extends Number

sealed trait UInt32 extends UnsignedNumber {
  def underlying : Long
}

sealed trait UInt64 extends UnsignedNumber {
  def underlying : BigInt
}

sealed trait Int32 extends SignedNumber {
  def underlying : Int
}

sealed trait Int64 extends SignedNumber {
  def underlying : Long
}
```

I would like to define `underlying` in the trait `Number` so the compiler can enforce that `underlying` is defined in all of the children. However, the types for `underlying` vary for each trait - I want to keep the smallest possible type for each type. For instance, a `UInt32` can be stored as a `long` in Scala, while a `UInt64` needs to be stored as a `BigInt`.

What is the most effective way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

You can declare a `type` in the parent trait and override it in the subtraits.

```
sealed trait Number {
  type A
  def underlying: A
  def + (num : Number) : Number = ???
  def - (num : Number) : Number = ???
  def * (num : Number) : Number = ???
}

sealed trait SignedNumber extends Number

sealed trait UnsignedNumber extends Number

sealed trait UInt32 extends UnsignedNumber {
  override type A = Long
}

sealed trait UInt64 extends UnsignedNumber {
  override type A = BigInt
}

sealed trait Int32 extends SignedNumber {
  override type A = Int
}

sealed trait Int64 extends SignedNumber {
  override type A = Long
}
```

An example just to show use of the path-dependent type in case that isn't clear:

```
def getUnderlying(x: Number): x.A = x.underlying
```

To get the return types correct, I think another `type` might be required.

```
sealed trait Number {
  type A
  type B
  def underlying: A
  def +(that: B): B
}

sealed trait UInt32 extends Number { x =>
  override type A = Long
  override type B = UInt32
  override def +(y: B): B = new UInt32 {
    // todo - naive implementation, doesn't check overflow
    override val underlying = x.underlying + y.underlying
  }
}

def main(args: Array[String]) {
  print((
    new UInt32 { def underlying = 3 } +
    new UInt32 { def underlying = 4 }
  ).underlying)
}
```

Comment: So I thought about taking this approach - Ocaml uses this all the time in their modules. How would implement signatures on things such as `+`, `-`, `*`? Would you have the type `A` be returned for all of those functions? That leads to the question of how does the end user actually access the underlying type? Some function (a : A) : <underlying type here>?

Comment: Also does having `underlying` in a public scope undermine type encapsulation? I'm on the fence I guess...

Comment: Edited with some more thoughts. I guess you'll have to decide whether you want the underlying type/value to be exposed or not. I suppose you might also consider making a `Number` type class instead of using inheritance.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way is to store the primitive numbers (Int Double...) as the raw type.

The unsignedness should be stored in a Type parameter, which will be erased at runtime. Scala does this when you let simple case classes extend AnyVal.

The folowing code does this for Ints, Longs, Doubles and Bigint.
I added a few classifications in adition to unsigned and renamed unsigned to positive.

Also since the classification is all done in the type-system we do not need to provide as many overloaded + - and * functions. This will save space when trying to implement this for all the number types.

There is still a little to be done when bridging between the various types. I will have a look at this later.

The Classification traits:

```
sealed trait SignTag{
  type SubTag <:SignTag;
  type AddTag <:SignTag;
  type MultTag<:SignTag;
}

sealed trait Signed extends SignTag{
  type SubTag=Signed;
  type AddTag=Signed;
  type MultTag=Signed;
}

sealed trait Positive extends SignTag{
  type SubTag=Signed;
  type AddTag=Negative;
  type MultTag=Negative;
}

sealed trait Negative extends SignTag{
  type SubTag=Signed;
  type AddTag=Negative;
  type MultTag=Positive;
}

sealed trait Zero extends SignTag{
  type SubTag=Zero;
  type AddTag=Zero;
  type MultTag=Zero;
}
```

Int wrapper:

```
object SInt {
  @inline
  implicit def toSigned[T <: SignTag](int:SInt[T]):SInt[Signed]=int.asInstanceOf[SInt[Signed]];

  @inline implicit def toLong[T <: SignTag](int:SInt[T]):SLong[T]=SLong(int.underlying);
  @inline implicit def toDouble[T <: SignTag](int:SInt[T]):SDouble[T]=SDouble(int.underlying);
  @inline implicit def toBig[T <: SignTag](int:SInt[T]):SBigInt[T]=SBigInt(int.underlying);
}

case class SInt[T <: SignTag](val underlying:Int) extends AnyVal{
  def -(second: SInt[_ <: T#InTag]):SInt[T#SubTag]=new SInt[T#SubTag](underlying - second.underlying);

  def +(second: SInt[_ <: T#InTag]):SInt[T#AddTag]=new SInt[T#AddTag](underlying + second.underlying);

  def *(second: SInt[_ <: T#InTag]):SInt[T#MultTag]=new SInt[T#MultTag](underlying * second.underlying);

  def assertSameType(other:SInt[T])={};
}
```

Long wrapper:

```
object SLong {

  @inline
  implicit def toSigned[T <: SignTag](int:SLong[T]):SLong[Signed]=int.asInstanceOf[SLong[Signed]];

  @inline implicit def toDouble[T <: SignTag](int:SLong[T]):SDouble[T]=SDouble(int.underlying);
  @inline implicit def toBig[T <: SignTag](int:SLong[T]):SBigInt[T]=SBigInt(int.underlying);
}

case class SLong[T <: SignTag](val underlying:Long) extends AnyVal{
  def -(second: SLong[_ <: T#InTag]):SLong[T#SubTag]=new SLong[T#SubTag](underlying - second.underlying);

  def +(second: SLong[_ <: T#InTag]):SLong[T#AddTag]=new SLong[T#AddTag](underlying + second.underlying);

  def *(second: SLong[_ <: T#InTag]):SLong[T#MultTag]=new SLong[T#MultTag](underlying * second.underlying);

  def assertSameType(other:SLong[T])={};
}
```

Double wrapper:

```
object SDouble {
  @inline
  implicit def toSigned[T <: SignTag](int:SDouble[T]):SDouble[Signed]=int.asInstanceOf[SDouble[Signed]];
}

case class SDouble[T <: SignTag](val underlying:Double) extends AnyVal{
  def -(second: SDouble[_ <: T#InTag]):SDouble[T#SubTag]=new SDouble[T#SubTag](underlying - second.underlying);

  def +(second: SDouble[_ <: T#InTag]):SDouble[T#AddTag]=new SDouble[T#AddTag](underlying + second.underlying);

  def *(second: SDouble[_ <: T#InTag]):SDouble[T#MultTag]=new SDouble[T#MultTag](underlying * second.underlying);

  def assertSameType(other:SDouble[T])={};
}
```

BigInt wrapper:

```
object SBigInt {
  @inline
  implicit def toSigned[T <: SignTag](int:SLong[T]):SLong[Signed]=int.asInstanceOf[SLong[Signed]];

  @inline
  implicit def toDouble[T <: SignTag](int:SBigInt[T]):SDouble[T]=SDouble(int.underlying.toDouble);
}

case class SBigInt[T <: SignTag](val underlying:BigInt) extends AnyVal{
  def -(second: SBigInt[_ <: T#InTag]):SBigInt[T#SubTag]=new SBigInt[T#SubTag](underlying - second.underlying);

  def +(second: SBigInt[_ <: T#InTag]):SBigInt[T#AddTag]=new SBigInt[T#AddTag](underlying + second.underlying);

  def *(second: SBigInt[_ <: T#InTag]):SBigInt[T#MultTag]=new SBigInt[T#MultTag](underlying * second.underlying);

  def assertSameType(other:SBigInt[T])={};
}
```

Test the syntax:

```
class CompileToTest {
  val signed=new SInt[Signed](5);
  val positive=new SInt[Positive](5);
  val negative=new SInt[Negative](-5);
  val zero=new SInt[Zero](0);

  (signed + signed).assertSameType(signed);
  (negative + signed).assertSameType(signed);
  (positive - positive).assertSameType(signed);
  (positive * negative).assertSameType(signed);
  (zero + zero).assertSameType(zero);

  val positiveDouble=SDouble[Positive](4.4)
  val negativeDouble=SDouble[Negative](-4.4)
  val signedDouble=SDouble[Signed](-4.4)

  (positiveDouble * negativeDouble).assertSameType(signedDouble);
}
```

Ps. Haven't actually looked at the bytecode, but the docs sugests that this should be inlined and compiled down to primitives.

I just love this lanuage.